# Accessing the HTML Button ID in TS file (Ionic)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm looking to call the HTML button ID into my TS file. I know it's not best practice to use "getElementByID" (or so I've read) in Ionic. Was wondering what the appropriate approach would be.

Here is my Code...

HTML

```
<button id="B" value="{{gamer[indexCount].correct}}" ion-button class="answerButtona" block (click)="answerClicked('B')">
    {{gamer[indexCount].B}}
  </button>
```

TS

```
answerClicked(ans){
//this is my function now
}


let body = {
    user_id: this.gamer[this.indexCount]['ID'],
    userAnswer: **Looking to call ans here**
}
```

I'm now passing in a parameter to the function. How would I access the parameter. this.ans doesn't seem to be working.

EDIT: Update to the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to make `answerClickedB()` set something like `this.userAnswer = 'B'` and then use this.userAnswer.

Or even better:

```
(click)=`answerClicked('B')` in the HTML
```

and this in the .ts

```
answerClicked(ans) {
    this.userAnswer = ans;
}
```

You're right that your approach is not the 'ionic' way. The 'ionic' way or 'angular' way is to use bindings, not gets on DOM elements.

Comment: How would I access it in the "body" like shown above

Comment: `this.userAnswer`

Comment: I'm getting a "userAnswer is not defined"

Comment: define it in the top of your ts file: `public userAnswer : any;`

Answer (score 2):

The best approach to get access to Dom elements in angular(ionic) would be by using @ViewChild

You can use a reference to target that specific element like this:

```
<div #myElement></div>
```

inside you ts now you can have access to that element using these imports and the @ViewChild:

```
import {ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('myElement') myElement: ElementRef;

constructor(){

}
```

and then access it like this :

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.myElement.nativeElement);
}
```

Comment: I'm looking to just get the "ID" of "B" called. I want to do this for A, B, C, D as well. I just used B as an example

Comment: Do you want to get ids after you click or fire some events or do you want it when page loads

Comment: Yeah after the user clicks (answerClickedA, answerClickedB, etc, etc) I would like to grab the ID of what button the user clicks

Comment: If that is the case then try passing string value inside the function you trigger on click or tap like this
(click)=answerClicked('b') and access it inside your ts

Comment: What value do you want to set to the userAnswer property inside your ts btw

Comment: Ok great - I've updated my code - hopefully that will help